# Evaluating q-analogy. Kostant partition function in a Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

It is a question to me that why we evaluate Kostant or q-analogue Kostant partition function for the highest root of a Lie algebra and if we have these calculations, can we derive these partition functions for an arbitrary weight and root from those?

Comment: It's very hard (apart from English grammar) to understand what the question is about, not just "drive" for "derive".   Also, there is a need for more tags such as 'lie-algebras' and maybe 'rt.representation-theory'.

Comment: Dear Jim, I mean that is it possible to compute the q-analog of Kostants's weight multiplicity with respect to an arbitrary root and weight from the highest root?